# HTMLEditorExtender causing 'Key cannot be null' error

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, html-editor

My project in ASP.Net C# is compiling and running fine except for when I try to load a specific page which has an Ajax Control Toolkit HTMLEditorExtender on it.  I get a Key cannot be null page error. I tried removing the htmleditorextender and putting an asynchfileupload control instead just to make sure the scriptmanager was working, and the page comes up fine and the upload control works.  So it is something with the htmleditorextender specifically.  Here is the code I have:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMailMsgContent" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"/>
<cc1:HtmlEditorExtender ID="HTMLEditorExtender" runat="server" 
TargetControlID="txtMailMsgContent">

            <Toolbar> 
                <cc1:Undo />
                <cc1:Redo />
                <cc1:Bold />
                <cc1:Italic />
                <cc1:Underline />
                <cc1:StrikeThrough />
                <cc1:Subscript />
                <cc1:Superscript />
                <cc1:JustifyLeft />
                <cc1:JustifyCenter />
                <cc1:JustifyRight />
                <cc1:JustifyFull />
                <cc1:InsertOrderedList />
                <cc1:InsertUnorderedList />
                <cc1:CreateLink />
                <cc1:UnLink />
                <cc1:RemoveFormat />
                <cc1:SelectAll />
                <cc1:UnSelect />
                <cc1:Delete />
                <cc1:Cut />
                <cc1:Copy />
                <cc1:Paste />
                <cc1:BackgroundColorSelector />
                <cc1:ForeColorSelector />
                <cc1:FontNameSelector />
                <cc1:FontSizeSelector />
                <cc1:Indent />
                <cc1:Outdent />
                <cc1:InsertHorizontalRule />
                <cc1:HorizontalSeparator />
            </Toolbar>
        </cc1:HtmlEditorExtender>
```

The line that shows the error on the page error is this one:

```
   <cc1:HtmlEditorExtender ID="HTMLEditorExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtMailMsgContent">
```

This is the stack trace:

```
[ArgumentNullException: Key cannot be null.
Parameter name: key]
   System.Collections.Hashtable.get_Item(Object key) +9355627
   AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.Sanitizer.Initialize() +163
   AjaxControlToolkit.HtmlEditorExtender..ctor() +54
   ASP.mail_emailmessage_aspx.__BuildControlHTMLEditorExtender() in c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Mail\EMailMessage.aspx:111
   ASP.mail_emailmessage_aspx.__BuildControlformMailMessage() in c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Mail\EMailMessage.aspx:84
   ASP.mail_emailmessage_aspx.__BuildControlTree(mail_emailmessage_aspx __ctrl) in c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Mail\EMailMessage.aspx:1
   ASP.mail_emailmessage_aspx.FrameworkInitialize() in c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\26676eb7\92c7e946\App_Web_kemmoois.0.cs:0
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +54
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() +78
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context) +21
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +49
   ASP.mail_emailmessage_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\26676eb7\92c7e946\App_Web_kemmoois.0.cs:0
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +100
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
```

Any help would be greatly appreaciated. I've tried googling this error and can't find a solution that seems to work.

Comment: Try the solution offered by Bertzzie in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022493/could-not-load-type-ajaxcontroltoolkit-sanitizer-antixsssanitizerprovider .
It Works for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>    
        <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox1">
        </asp:CalendarExtender>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <cc1:Editor ID="Editor1" runat="server" />
        <asp:HtmlEditorExtender ID="HtmlEditorExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox2">
        </asp:HtmlEditorExtender>
        <asp:AnimationExtender ID="AnimationExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox3" >
        </asp:AnimationExtender>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

> Try This code and don't make any changes in the web.config file I was
>   getting the same exception earlier but when i tried this It got
>   resolved

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will be your problem, but I encountered this when I didn't have the following section in my web.config in system.web:

> ```
>    <sanitizer defaultProvider="AntiXssSanitizerProvider">
>        <providers>
>            <add name="AntiXssSanitizerProvider" type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.AntiXssSanitizerProvider"></add>
>        </providers>
>    </sanitizer>
> ```

You'll also need to have this in your configsections:

> ```
>    <sectionGroup name="system.web">
>        <section name="sanitizer" requirePermission="false"
>                 type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.ProviderSanitizerSection, AjaxControlToolkit" />
>    </sectionGroup>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add these lines to your web.config

Configsectons:

```
<configSections>
   <sectionGroup name="system.web">
      <section name="sanitizer" requirePermission="false" type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.ProviderSanitizerSection, AjaxControlToolkit" />
   </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
```

System.web

```
<system.web>
   <sanitizer defaultProvider="AntiXssSanitizerProvider">
    <providers>
      <add name="AntiXssSanitizerProvider"   type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider" />
    </providers>
  </sanitizer>
```

Your troubles should go away as they did for me.
If its of any help I found the solution by looking in the Object browser.