# Could not load type 'AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.AntiXssSanitizerProvider'.

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I tried to use htmleditorextender but I am getting error. below are my settings

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="textBoxGalleryUrl" CssClass="cstmtxtclr" />
<asp:HtmlEditorExtender ID="HtmlEditorExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="textBoxGalleryUrl"></asp:HtmlEditorExtender>
```

My web.conf settings are;

```
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web">
      <section name="sanitizer"
          requirePermission="false"
          type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.ProviderSanitizerSection, AjaxControlToolkit"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web>
    <!--<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>-->
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>

    <sanitizer defaultProvider="AntiXssSanitizerProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="AntiXssSanitizerProvider"
              type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.AntiXssSanitizerProvider"></add>
      </providers>
    </sanitizer>
  </system.web>
```

I have the following dlls in my bin folder;

```
AntiXSSLibrary.dll
SanitizerProviders.dll
HtmlSanitizationLibrary.dll
```

But I still get this error;

```
Could not load type 'AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.AntiXssSanitizerProvider'.
```

**Why I am getting this error?**

Comment: Try the solution offered by Bertzzie in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022493/could-not-load-type-ajaxcontroltoolkit-sanitizer-antixsssanitizerprovider .
It Works for me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using `AntiXss` as the default sanitizer is [no longer supported](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2012/06/25/announcing-the-june-2012-release-of-the-ajax-control-toolkit.aspx) as of June 2012. From the official announcement, apparantely the new version of `AntiXss` breaks too many things.

To use AjaxControlToolkit with `HTML Agility Pack` you first need to install the pacakge using Nuget ([instruction](http://nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack)).

Then you can use `HTML Agility Pack` as your sanitizer by modifying your `web.config` like this:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web">
            <section name="sanitizer" requirePermission="false"
                     type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.ProviderSanitizerSection, AjaxControlToolkit" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>

    <system.web>
        <sanitizer defaultProvider="HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider">
            <providers>
                <add name="HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider" type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider"></add>
            </providers>
        </sanitizer>
      </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried but I m getting this -> Could not load file or assembly 'HtmlAgilityPack, Version=1.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bd319b19eaf3b43a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: Have you installed the `HTML Agility Pack` from Nuget? I did remember installing that first, and I don't have to setup anything...

Comment: i am using this but it doesn't even remove <script>alert('asdas')</script> @MikeKingscott

Answer (score 2):

[HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) must be installed for all new versions of Ajax Control Toolkit.
Unfortunetly a lot of answers in the web are wrong

Answer (score 1):

Having searched high and low for the same problem to be solved, I worked out that the Ajax Control Kit also needed to be loaded via the Library Package Manager...

*PM* > *Install-Package AjaxControlToolkit*

This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended that you download the latest Html Agility Pack from here :
http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ and place in your bin and add reference to it in your project.

**Or use the install command :**

PM> Install-Package HtmlAgilityPack

you may look at this link http://nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack

You don't have to use or reference to AntiXSSLibrary just use the HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider and your error will disappear

Good luck

Comment: hsobhy how do i use only htmlagilitypacksanitizerprovider can you explain ?