# Ajax htmlEditorExtender - Unrecognized element sanitizer

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, web-config

Hi I've downloaded the latest version of the Ajax Toolkit from Microsoft and I'm trying to setup the sanitizer for the htmlEditorExtender, but I keep getting the following error when trying to build the site:

> "Unrecognized element 'sanitizer.'"

Following the guide on the Ajax site I've tried to add the following:

```
<compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <sanitizer defaultProvider="AntiXssSanitizerProvider">
    <providers>
      <add name="AntiXssSanitizerProvider"
           type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.AntiXssSanitizerProvider"></add>
    </providers>
  </sanitizer>
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

To my web.config along with:

```
<sectionGroup name="system.web">
  <section name="sanitizer"
      requirePermission="false"
      type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.ProviderSanitizerSection, 
    AjaxControlToolkit"/>
</sectionGroup>
```

I'm quite new to ASP.net and VB.net and I've never used the Ajax toolkit before. In my Bin folder I have the AjaxControlToolkit.dll which was installed when following the instructions to add the toolkit controls to the Toolbox.

Is there something that I'm missing or need to do to allow this to all work correctly?

Answer (score 3):

Put `<sanitizer>` tag **directly** after `<system.web>` as below:

```
<system.web>
    <sanitizer defaultProvider="HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider" type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider"></add>
      </providers>
    </sanitizer>
```

Use `HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider` than `AntiXssSanitizerProvider`
[Referring to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12038532/1166597) "Using AntiXss as the default sanitizer is no longer supported as of June 2012. From the official announcement, apparantely the new version of AntiXss breaks too many things."

Same goes for `<sectionGroup>` also as the **first tag** after `<configuration>`

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web">
      <section name="sanitizer"
          requirePermission="false"
          type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.ProviderSanitizerSection, 
        AjaxControlToolkit"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
```

This solved my case with the same error.